# Removing specific HTTP response header

Tags: 7, http-request

I am trying to remove specific HTTP response header from my site. 
The header looks like this:

```
Link: <https://example.com>; rel="canonical",<https://example.com>; rel="shortlink"
```

So far I have tried this simple code in my `theme_html_head_alter`:

```
header_remove("Link");
```

But that does not remove the header. Is there some specific Drupal way to deal with this, or am I using this code in wrong function? Or am I completely wrong with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it using `hook_html_head_alter` like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_html_head_alter().
 */
function myTheme_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  foreach ($head_elements as $key => $head_element) {
    if (strpos($key, 'drupal_add_html_head_link:shortlink') === 0) {
      unset($head_elements[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

**PS :** the above code remove links with `rel="shortlink"` if you want to remove links with `rel="canonical"` just add another if and change `shortlink` by `canonical`.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.